# Saving and retrieving CLOB data greater than 32K in Oracle Apex

Tags: plsql, onload, oracle-apex, clob

My aim is to retrieve CLOB data from the database into a textarea in an Oracle Apex application and then to be able to save it into the database from the textarea itself on pressing a 'Save' button. I also have some other fields on this page (as textfields) which are non CLOB fields and they need to be saved in the database as well on clicking the button.

For this, I'm using the following code under "HTML Header and Body Attribute" of the page. This is used to retrieve/save CLOB into the textarea/database. Note that a simple PLSQL code inside the Apex item will suffice to do what I'm doing here but only if CLOB data is less than 32k bytes. I am using this function due to the 32k limit in plsql in apex (and 4k limit when sql is used).

```
function clob_set(){  
        var clob_ob = new apex.ajax.clob(  
            function(){  
                var rs = p.readyState  
                if(rs == 1||rs == 2||rs == 3){  
                    $x_Show('AjaxLoading');  
                }else if(rs == 4){  
                    $s('P5075_RESPONSETEXT',p.responseText);  
                    $x_Hide('AjaxLoading');  
                }else{return false;}  
            }  
        );  

        if(!$v_IsEmpty('P5075_STYLESHEET')){clob_ob._set($v('P5075_STYLESHEET'))};  
    }  

    function clob_get(){  
        var clob_ob = new apex.ajax.clob(  
            function(){  
                var rs = p.readyState  
                if(rs == 1||rs == 2||rs == 3){  
                    $x_Show('AjaxLoading');  
                }else if(rs == 4){  
                    $s('P5075_STYLESHEET',p.responseText);  
                    $x_Hide('AjaxLoading');  
                }else{return false;}  
            }  
        );  
        clob_ob._get();  
    }
```

I am calling one of the functions under "Page HTML Body Attribute" as **onload = "javascript:clob_get();"**

I have a PLSQL after header process for this.

```
declare
l_clob clob:= empty_clob();

begin

if apex_collection.collection_exists(p_collection_name=>'CLOB_CONTENT') then
apex_collection.delete_collection(p_collection_name=>'CLOB_CONTENT');
end if;

apex_collection.create_or_truncate_collection(p_collection_name=>'CLOB_CONTENT');
dbms_lob.createtemporary( l_clob, false, dbms_lob.SESSION );

SELECT xslt
INTO l_clob
FROM schematransform
WHERE namn = 'f';

apex_collection.add_member(p_collection_name => 'CLOB_CONTENT',p_clob001 => l_clob);
end;
```

This is working just fine. Now, I have a plsql process which saves the details entered in the CLOB and non-CLOB fields into the database. But as soon as the page submits, I get a "HTTP Bad Request".

Can anyone please explain why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: What apex version are you on? 4.0? 4.1? Lower? What is the size of the clob you are testing with? Have you tried with a <32k clob? Or a <4k? Take a read through https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=723735 and http://www.advnettech.net/blog/?p=7 , those seem to handle this kind of problem, and seem to indicate a problem with apex.ajax.clob and >32k.

Comment: I'm using Apex 4.1. I have tested with CLOB size as small as 90 bytes and as large as 50k bytes. I am having the same issue. 

I'm getting the CLOB in the textarea correctly. It's just that when I call the javascript function when the page loads and then submit the page, I get this error.

The process that is saving the textfields is of type "PLSQL Anonymous block" and the process point is "On Load - After Header". This process gets submitted when I click on a Submit button named "Save".The problem I see is some conflict between 'page onload calling javascript' and 'page submit' after that.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly: Page loads, on-load fires, you get clob values. You make edits. You click a button which submits the page, and you expect the fields with clob-values to be saved to the collection? Correct?

Comment: Almost correct. I am not saving the fields with CLOB values (for now). There are some other fields as well besides CLOB (like name, title) which are just VARCHAR. On submit, I want to save these values in the database.

Comment: If the error is on submit, it is possible that you need to first remove the value from the item containing the clob so that it is not submitted along with the other fields. You could do this by disabling the item or making it display only. Or you could rewire your submit process to first null that item's value.

Comment: Greg, that makes sense. Thanks a lot! I was moving one step at a time. That's why I removed clob out of the equation for now. 

I am getting the clob data in the texarea.
I am able to save the non clob fields in database (by making clob field as display only)

What i want now : to submit page and save the clob details (editing through textarea) and the non clob details in the database.

Comment: Please excuse me for all the confusion, I'm new to this and all confused so as how to proceed (and even how to explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for apex.ajax.clob, taken from apex_4_1.js:

```
/**
 * @namespace = apex.ajax
 */
apex.ajax = {
    /*clob*/
    clob : function (pReturn){
        var that = this;
        this.ajax = new htmldb_Get(null,$x('pFlowId').value,'APXWGT',0);
        this.ajax.addParam('p_widget_name','apex_utility');
        this.ajax.addParam('x04','CLOB_CONTENT');
        this._get = _get;
        this._set = _set;
        this._return = !!pReturn?pReturn:_return;
        return;
        function _get(pValue){
            that.ajax.addParam('x05','GET');
            that.ajax.GetAsync(that._return);
        }
        function _set(pValue){
            that.ajax.addParam('x05','SET');
            that.ajax.AddArrayClob(pValue,1);
            that.ajax.GetAsync(that._return);
        }
        function _return(){
        if(p.readyState == 1){
            }else if(p.readyState == 2){
            }else if(p.readyState == 3){
            }else if(p.readyState == 4){
              return p;
            }else{return false;}
        }
    },
```

So, clob setting and getting is truly asynchronuous. The code you posted provides a handling function that is called when the request is finished (done in htmldb_get). I think it's an ugly workaround but ok. We need to manipulate this function code for our submit to work. Since the set is async, we can't be sure that the page will not be submitted before the set has occured. To prevent this, amend your clob_set code as such:

```
function clob_set(pSubmit){
   var clob_ob = new apex.ajax.clob(
      function(){
         var rs = p.readyState
         if(rs == 1||rs == 2||rs == 3){
            $x_Show('AjaxLoading');
         }else if(rs == 4){
             //here the clob has actually been saved, and
             // the ajax call finished
            $s('P5075_RESPONSETEXT',p.responseText);
            $x_Hide('AjaxLoading');

            //pSubmit is a new param
            //use it to check if set has been called for
            //a page submit or not
            if(pSubmit){
               //disable the clob field: it should not be
               //substituted to the session state!!
               $('#P5075_STYLESHEET').prop("disabled", true);
               //actually submit the page. This will submit
               //all fields to session except the disabled ones
               apex.submit('SUBMIT');
            };
         }else{
            return false;
         };
      });

   if(!$v_IsEmpty('P5075_STYLESHEET')){
      clob_ob._set($v('P5075_STYLESHEET'));
   };
};
```

Alter your submit button, and have it's action be defined by a dynamic action. You need to do this to prevent the substitution of your clob-fields to the session through the default process. Create a dynamic action which executes javascript, call clob_set with pSubmit set:

```
clob_set(true);
```

Do have a look at the [apex.submit api description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/javascript_api.htm#CHDBEACA). Also understand how a button works: it submits the page and will set the request to the name of that button (or another request value if explicitly defined).

For example, a button could be named 'APPLY_CHANGES' and have a label 'Change'. This is important if you use for example the built-in row processing. The request value will determine which SQL-action will be invoked, and you can view the possible values in the details of the process, next to the checkboxes for insert/update/delete.

Here, a most helpful beautiful flowchart:

[image: clob_set flowchart]

Comment: I'm sorry Tom, I couldn't get it working. Just to be clear, you are telling me how to insert CLOB and non CLOB fields in the database right?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to _not_ let the fields which hold the clob value be submitted into session, since we want to avoid the 32k limits there. Non-clobs should be processed normally though. So, what i wanted to do here is to first save those clob fields through clob_set, then disable those clob-fields, and then submit the page. This should result in having your clob value in the collection, and your other items in session state. I hope that clob_set does what you/me/we expect from it though! If you have an error-code or so, post it. If my method is unclear, maybe an example could help?

Comment: Oh okay, now i get it. Thanks a lot for the wonderful explanation. Let me give my best shot to it now that I have understood it. I'll let you know if things work out or not.

Have a great weekend :)

Comment: Hi Tom! I tried with the dynamic actions. The non clob fields are getting saved now without a problem. The CLOB fields are getting saved but there's a problem in that. I have to press the 'Save' button twice to save it into the database. Here is what i have done.

I have called clob_get() in the footer of the region containing the clob field so that i get the clob data as soon as the page loads.

Comment: I have made a dynamic action on the 'Save' button with Event as 'Click'. I have 2 true actions. 1st is 'Execute Javascript code' which calls clob_set() when the button is clicked and 2nd is 'Execute plsql code' which is saving the clob and non clob fields in the database. The event scope in the dynamic action is 'bind'.

Comment: I have made a small change in clob_set() which i have posted above. I have used a textfield item 'P5075_RESPONSETEXT' which gets the message as 'SUCESS' if the clob_set() is called. In my case, when i press the 'Save' button, then i get the 'Success' text in the item and then again if i press 'Save', then the clob gets saved in the database. I understand that this is happening since my dynamic action is 'on click', but i couldn't figure how to correct it because if i change it to 'onchange' or something, then I'm getting the problem of 32k again.

Comment: There are some mistakes/misunderstandings i believe. First: i made a mistake: clob_set is ajax, and probably true ajax (unlike many other funcs in apex which are really synchronouos). Therefor, is unreliable to call this function and immediatly submit after it. Anyhow, your altered processing could be changed aswell: it is not necessary to change your clob to DB through a dynamic action. clob_set saves your clob-field to a collection, i'd simply write an after-submit process which then saves from collection to the DB. Your flow will be much clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by after-submit process in Apex? Do you mean the 'On-Demand' process? And, in this case, where and when do i call the 'clob_set()'?

Comment: clob_set has to be called through javascript, before anything is submitted. Having this on the onclick of a button is good. By after-submit process i mean, create a new process: not on-demand! The processing point should be after-submit or even after the validations. I say this because it is unnecessary to save your clob values to the DB through ajax, and before any validation has been done on your form. Having this process in your actual page processing flow will be much clearer than having it obscured in js code.

Comment: see the fantastic flowchart i added to my post, maybe that'll clarify

Comment: Nice flowchart Tom! According to it, now when my 'Save' button is making the javascript call for clob_set(), sometimes the field 'RESPONSETEXT' is getting 'SUCCESS' and sometimes it is getting the error 'The requested URL /apex/wwv_flow.show was not found on this server'. It is totally random. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Any comments on this?
(Right now I have not moved ahead of this step since this needs to be solved first)

Comment: and when i submit the page, I'm back at the starting point when I had posted the question. Submit is not working. It gives me 'Bad Request' I am so confused here.

Comment: Ok: first off. You altered the click on the submit. Did you do this as i described, ie -not- having the button submit, but have the button fire a dynamic action? In this dynamic action, is there the code i posted (especially the disabling of the clob field is key)? If yes to both: are you testing your clob field with plenty of data? Are you trying with >30k? Just making sure.

Comment: I edited my post again, hopefully even better explaining what is (or might be) happening - it might be that the ajax is spoiling the party so far!

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood some things. Okay now I am doing as you told. I have my SAVE button defined by the dynamic action. The dynamic action fires when the 'SAVE' button is clicked and has the following javascript code: clob_set();
$('#P5075_STYLESHEET').prop("disabled", true); 
apex.submit('SAVE');

Then, I have created a process which is firing after submit and saving the clob and non clob fields in database. My non-clob data is getting saved. However, the clob data is NOT getting saved. I am trying both for data >32K and <32K. Both bear the same results.

Comment: Take a look at the JS code i edited for the dynamic action too. Now for your clob_data not being saved: in your process, how are you getting your clob content? Selecting from the collection? (select clob001 from apex_collections where collection_name = 'CLOB_CONTENT') ? Does this trigger a no_data_found? Try step through your page processing with debug on, maybe you can spot something?

Comment: I've edited my clob_set() function and made a call in the dynamic action as you suggested. Yes, I'm getting the clob content in the process from the collection (select clob001 into v_clob from apex_collections where collection_name='CLOB_CONTENT';
). I'm using this value (through v_clob variable) to set the CLOB column in the database with an update statement. No I do not get a 'no data found' error (can't spot anything even with the debug on).

Comment: Okay, so that would mean that the clob actually has a value in it. Add a ´COMMIT;´ at the end of your process and see if that helps! If it doesn't, show a debug message with apex_debug_message.log_message(v_clob) and check it through your debug. If this is empty, the error has to be with clob_set (D:)

Comment: Tom, I made a small typo, It's working like a charm now! Thank you so much for helping me out all the way. I'm gonna rephrase my original question so that it can help others later. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

this is an old thread, but CLOB handling changed in new Apex, so i think this will useful for someone.

I use Apex 21.2 and the CLOB upload much simpler.

Item - Rich Text Editor (CKEDITOR5)
Submit button -> Submit

Javascript:

- Catch the Submit event
- Slice CLOB smaller parts
- Insert smaller parts into the Form
- Disable the original CLOB field

```
    apex.gPageContext$.on( "apexpagesubmit", function() {
        var $ = apex.jQuery,
        form$ = $( "#wwvFlowForm" ),
        f1 = apex.server.chunk( $v( "P1_CLOB_COLUMN" ) );
    
        if ( !Array.isArray( f1 ) ) {
            f1 = [f1];
        }
        
        f1.forEach( function( v ) {
            form$.append( "" );
        });
        
        $('#P1_CLOB_COLUMN').prop("disabled", true);
        $s( "P1_CLOB_COLUMN", "" );
    });
```

Then CLOB parts submitted in the normal way, no need Ajax Callback and COLLECTIONS.
Only need a Process that combine parts (after row processing),
and update the CLOB field. Because after the Row Processing, you have P1_ID_COLUMN too (if insert).

SetCLOB plsql:

```
    DECLARE
        l_clob CLOB;
    BEGIN
        l_clob := empty_clob();
        DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_clob,true);
    
        for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count 
        LOOP   
            l_clob := l_clob || apex_application.g_f01(i) ;
        END LOOP;
    
        Update CLOB_TABLE set 
        P1_CLOB_COLUMN= l_clob
        Where ID = :P1_ID_COLUMN;
    END;
```

Getting the CLOB to the RichText item - Javascript:
Copied getting code from: https://www.stinolez.com/2020/07/03/clob-in-apex-rich-text-editor/
Execute it when page loads.

```
    function getData() {
        apex.server.process("GetCLOB", {
            pageItems:['P1_ID_COLUMN']
          }, {
            dataType: 'html'
          }).done(function(rData) {
               $s('P1_CLOB_COLUMN',rData);
        });}
```

And the GetCLOB Ajax callback PL/SQL block:

```
    DECLARE
        l_clob        CLOB;
        l_file        BLOB;
        l_dest_offset PLS_INTEGER := 1;
        l_src_offset  PLS_INTEGER := 1;
        l_lang_ctx    PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
        l_csid        PLS_INTEGER := NLS_CHARSET_ID('UTF8');
        l_blob_warn   PLS_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            -- Get the CLOB
            SELECT NVL(P1_CLOB_COLUMN, EMPTY_CLOB())
            INTO l_clob
            FROM CLOB_TABLE
            WHERE ID = :P1_ID_COLUMN;
          -- Exception handling when no data were found for the ID (you are creating new row
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                l_clob := EMPTY_CLOB();
          
        END;
    
        -- If we don't have a CLOB, just return empty content
        IF (DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_clob) = 0) THEN
            HTP.P('');
        ELSE
            -- Create BLOB from CLOB
    
            DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(  lob_loc => l_file
                                 , cache => true
                                 , dur => DBMS_LOB.CALL);
            DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(l_file, l_clob, dbms_lob.lobmaxsize, l_dest_offset, l_src_offset, l_csid, l_lang_ctx, l_blob_warn);
            -- Download BLOB
            OWA_UTIL.MIME_HEADER('text/html', false);
            HTP.P('Content-Length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_file));
            HTP.P('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="content.html"');
            OWA_UTIL.HTTP_HEADER_CLOSE();
            WPG_DOCLOAD.DOWNLOAD_FILE(l_file);
        END IF;
    END;
```

Regards,
Józsi